# Unable to launch terminal (Gnome, Debian)

Tags: debian, linux

I have a Debian Squeeze server installment, on which I have installed Gnome (because I wanted to be able to use Remote Desktop from Windows and develop directly on the server).

This is working, however, when I try to open up a Gnome Terminal I get the following error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
```

I have search the web for an answer, and some places, people say it becuase the user is not in the `tty`group.
The user I log in with is `mol`.
Doing an `id`, I get `uid=1002(mol) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),5(tty),1002(mol)`. 
This user is in the `tty` group.

Other places on the web, people are saying it is because `/dev/pts` isn't mounted, as suggests that you add the following to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

This I have also added to my `/etc/fstab`. Running `mount` gives me this output:

```
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec)
```

So this device is mounted.

This is were I, and the pages I have reached in my search, run out of ideas.
What do I do?

PS. Running `xterm` from the run applications window gives no error, but also no terminal.

Comment: What happens when you log in on a console, set `$DISPLAY` appropriately and try to run `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you want me to try? I log into the server, get a gnome desktop. Then I ssh to the server, set `$DISPLAY` to `:12` in this case, and the run `gnome-terminal`? It gives me the same error message on the gnome desktop, but nothing more on the console.

Comment: Hmm, just tried this again. When running the console as `root` I do get a terminal up and running on the desktop. This is saying `Terminal (as superuser)` in the title field, and I am logged in as root in this terminal. So it is a permission problem? But where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around, searching through a lot of other sites online, I finally managed to get the terminals working.

Seems as if `MAKEDEV` was missing from `/dev/`, and a simple `ln -s /sbin/MAKEDEV /dev/MAKEDEV; /dev/MAKEDEV pts` worked wonders for my system.